# geopandas import not working with AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue, geopandas

We are already tried installation via

1. WHL
2. EGG
3. PIP install

Always getting Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj'"
Below job config from AWS Glue console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI3nc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a Python Shell Glue Job.  If yes, then I was able to get it to work using the following steps

1. Build a wheel file

- Created a setup.py file with just geopandas and pandas as requirements

> ```
> from setuptools import setup
> setup(
>     name="test_geopandas",
>     version="0.1",
>     packages=['test_geopandas'],
>     install_requires=['pandas', 'geopandas']
> )
> ```

- Install the packages and build the wheel file

> python3 setup.py develop
>
> python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

2. Push the wheel file to S3 bucket

> aws s3 cp {absolute-path-to-wheel-file} "s3://{bucket}/{path-to-lib-storage}/"

3. Add the absolute s3 location to the wheel file to Python Library Path in Glue Jobs

Go to Glue Jobs> Edit Job> Security configuration, script libraries, and job parameters (optional) > Python library path

My script was just single line with the geopandas import and it worked fine after trying this.

The first 2 steps are tried out as is from [How do I resolve "ImportError: No module named" in AWS Glue?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-import-error-no-module-named/)

You can find more information about adding Python libraries here - [Running Spark ETL Jobs with Reduced Startup Times](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/reduced-start-times-spark-etl-jobs.html#reduced-start-times-new-features)